# can a word embedding encode two concepts in an order?

Tags: word-embeddings

This question is from a homework in the Sequence Models course taught by Andrew Ng on Coursera (this is not related to a homework problem per se, just for general edification).

See the screenshot below where the homework was describing cosine similarity. I was a little confused about the example to the right, where "France - Paris" and "Rome - Italy" were taken to be nearly opposites because one is country-city and the other is city-country.

Can an embedding really encode two different concepts with an "ordering" like this, or is this just a very contrived example?

[image]